Uniswap polygon price fetching fails
When i try to fetch the current price of tokens in ethereum mainnet it work stotally fine.
'use server'

import { AlchemyProvider, ethers, Network } from "ethers";
import { CurrencyAmount, TradeType } from '@uniswap/sdk-core';
import { Pair } from '@uniswap/v2-sdk';
import { Route, Trade } from '@uniswap/v2-sdk';
import uniswapV2poolABI from '@uniswap/v2-core/build/UniswapV2Pair.json';
import JSBI from "jsbi";

const alchemyProvider = new AlchemyProvider(new Network('mainnet', 1), process.env.ALCHEMY_PROVIDER_KEY, {
    alchemy_fetch: {
      cache: false,
    },
  })

const abi = uniswapV2poolABI.abi;


export async function Mock_createPairOnUniswap(token1, token2) {
    const pairAddress = Pair.getAddress(token1, token2);
    const pairContract = new ethers.Contract(pairAddress, abi, alchemyProvider);
    const reserves = await pairContract.getReserves({ cache: false });
    let [reserve0, reserve1] = reserves.map(reserve => reserve.toString());
    reserve0 = JSBI.BigInt(reserve0);
    reserve1 = JSBI.BigInt(reserve1);
    console.log('mainnet', reserve0, reserve1)
    const tokens = [token1, token2];
    const pair = new Pair(CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(tokens[0], reserve0), CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(tokens[1], reserve1));
    return pair;
  }


  export async function Mock_grabExecutionPriceFromUniswap(pair, token1, token2){
    const route = new Route([pair], token2, token1);
    const trade = new Trade(route, CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(token2, ethers.parseUnits('1', token2.decimals).toString()), TradeType.EXACT_INPUT);
    console.log('value: ', trade.executionPrice.toSignificant(6))
    return trade.executionPrice.toSignificant(6)
  }



The console.log gives
mainnet JSBI(3) [ 58201176, 1075274282, 416602, sign: false ] JSBI(3) [ 618654150, -636078256, 155, sign: false ]

value: 2664.12

but when I try the same for tokens in polygon network it gives output value which is too small, I don't understand what does it means.
'use server'

import { AlchemyProvider, ethers, Network } from "ethers";
import { CurrencyAmount, TradeType } from '@uniswap/sdk-core';
import { Pair } from '@uniswap/v2-sdk';
import { Route, Trade } from '@uniswap/v2-sdk';
import uniswapV2poolABI from '@uniswap/v2-core/build/UniswapV2Pair.json';
import JSBI from "jsbi";

const alchemyProvider = new AlchemyProvider(new Network('matic', 137), process.env.ALCHEMY_PROVIDER_KEY, {
    alchemy_fetch: {
      cache: false,
    },
  })

const abi = uniswapV2poolABI.abi;


export async function createPairOnUniswap(token1, token2) {
    const pairAddress = Pair.getAddress(token1, token2);
    const pairContract = new ethers.Contract(pairAddress, abi, alchemyProvider);
    const reserves = await pairContract.getReserves({ cache: false });
    let [reserve0, reserve1] = reserves.map(reserve => reserve.toString());
    reserve0 = JSBI.BigInt(reserve0);
    reserve1 = JSBI.BigInt(reserve1);
    console.log('polygon', reserve0, reserve1)
    const tokens = [token1, token2];
    const pair = new Pair(CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(tokens[0], reserve0), CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(tokens[1], reserve1));
    return pair;
  }


  export async function grabExecutionPriceFromUniswap(pair, token1, token2){
    const route = new Route([pair], token2, token1);
    const trade = new Trade(route, CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(token2, ethers.parseUnits('1', token2.decimals).toString()), TradeType.EXACT_INPUT);
    console.log('value: ', trade.executionPrice.toSignificant(6))
    return trade.executionPrice.toSignificant(6)
  }



this code gives a output as
polygon JSBI(2) [ 70345362, 108349, sign: false ] JSBI(2) [ 1172855432, 291095357, sign: false ]
value: 0.000206457

Why is the value this small?  Where do I need to change the calculation logic? Is this because of the uniswap v2 liquidity pool?
The input data I used are:
const chainId = ChainId.POLYGON;
    const tokenAddress1 = '0x8f3Cf7ad23Cd3CaDbD9735AFf958023239c6A063'; 
    const tokenAddress2 = '0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619'; 
    const decimals1 = 18;
    const decimals2 = 18;
    const tokenSymbol1 = 'DAI';
    const tokenSymbol2 = 'WETH';

    const Mock_chainId = ChainId.MAINNET;
    const tokenAddress3 = '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F'; 
    const tokenAddress4 = '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2'; 
    const decimals3 = 18;
    const decimals4 = 18;
    const tokenSymbol3 = 'DAI';
    const tokenSymbol4 = 'WETH';

    const token1 = new Token(chainId, tokenAddress1, decimals1, tokenSymbol1);
    const token2 = new Token(chainId, tokenAddress2, decimals2, tokenSymbol2);
    const token3 = new Token(Mock_chainId, tokenAddress3, decimals3, tokenSymbol3);
    const token4 = new Token(Mock_chainId, tokenAddress4, decimals4, tokenSymbol4);

Can anyone help to solve this? is it not possible to trade on polygon network on uniswap, programmatically? Why am I not getting accurate values?

You can find a Polygon Uniswap v2 price example written in Python here. You can study the source code and translate it to JavaScript.

why arent you sorting the tokens when making the pair? Also the price is returned in one direction you may need to invert the price depdening on token0/token1 e.g 1/price
